# Se puede hacer esto con Jquery y como lo podría hacer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

se puede enviar a dos paginas una variable desde jquery?, por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente jquery que me envia la variable a la pagina a.php, pero también deseo pasar esa misma variable a b.php

```
$(document).on('click','.hola', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
       url:"a.php", 
       method:"POST",
       data:{id:id},
       success:function(data){
           $('#employee_detail').html(data);
           $('#dataModal').modal('show');
       }
       });
})
```

Se podrá?.

Comment: No veo ningún problema, pero creo que te hubiera resultado más fácil probarlo que preguntarlo.

Comment: en teoria no habria ningun problema, salvo que tengas que esperar cierta respesta del  primer ajax , en dicho caso una vez concluido el "success" del primero llamas al segundo..!!

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, he tratado pero no lo logro realizar, me pueden hechar una ayudita en esto?, gracias.

Comment: Puedes por favor explicar lo que intentas hacer. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué en vez de plantearte enviar desde ajax datos a `a.php` y a `b.php` no envías los datos a `a.php` y desde ahí envías los datos a `b.php`?. Me parece más lógico puesto que una vez hecha la petición y enviarla a `a.php` ya estás en un entorno de servidor y por tanto es más fácil desde allí hacer cualquier operación relativa al servidor, como sería la invocación a `b.php`. Aquí lo fundamental es saber qué quieres hacer, qué relación tienen ambos archivos y sobre todo qué harás con los datos que estos devuelvan.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, gracias por el interes, la verdad es que tienen relacion, ya que a.php inserta y b.php muestra, cuando abro a.php me muestra unas preguntas pero a su vez me traigo de b.php una tabla de lo que hay registrado en la BD,lo describo,a un boton le doy click,envio la id a a.php,este muestra unas preguntas y al lado de las preguntas muestra la tabla de votos,cuando en a.php inserto la tabla de b.php me debe actualizar con ese voto enviado a la BD, espero me entiendan. Por eso necesito pasar a las dos paginas esa variable que envio desde el jquery.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Agrega otro ajax mas abajo que envie a b.php

```
$(document).on('click','.hola', function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
   url:"a.php", 
   method:"POST",
   data:{id:id},
   success:function(data){
       $('#employee_detail').html(data);
       $('#dataModal').modal('show');
   }
   });

$.ajax({
   url:"b.php", 
   method:"POST",
   data:{id:id},
   success:function(data){
 // change this çresult for 2nd page if need
       $('#employee_detail2').html(data);
       $('#dataModal2').modal('show');
   }
   });
})
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @GusZL es la correcta si no tienen dependencia entre sí, pero si necesitas que la variable enviada a ambas páginas a fuerza te tenga que devolver un resultado en ambas paginas, lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente (solo modificando un poco la respuesta de @GusZL):

```
$(document).on('click','.hola', function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
  url:"a.php", 
  method:"POST",
  data:{id:id},
  success:function(data){
    $.ajax({
      url:"b.php", 
      method:"POST",
      data:{id:id},
      success:function(data2){
        //Datos del primer ajax (a.php)
        $('#employee_detail').html(data);
        $('#dataModal').modal('show');
        //Datos del segundo ajax (b.php)
        $('#employee_detail2').html(data2);
        $('#dataModal2').modal('show');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Saludos